# What is an easy-to-implement linear or non-quadratic suffix array construction algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, strings, suffix-array

The algorithm described here in ["Linear Work Suffix Array Construction"](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/tpkarkka/publications/jacm05-revised.pdf) (2006) has compact C++ code that is too abstract for me to follow. Is that still the current easy-to-implement linear algorithm? If no, please point out that other algorithm. If yes, are there any other easier to follow reference implementations?

Comment: (Try beautifying the source code from your link and narrow down what about it is too abstract (_after_ trying to understand the parts of the paper that pertain to the implementation)). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array#Construction_Algorithms) mentions [SA-IS](https://sites.google.com/site/yuta256/sais).

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/10253/5693) on CSTheory.

Comment: @greybeard thanks for the suggestion to beautifying the source for the purposes of clarifying my (mis)understandings. Will do. Also that link suffix array induced sorting (SA-IS) algorithm with benchmark is a gem. SA-IS beats 4 other SA algorithms nearly every time for 22 benchmarks in terms of both time and space.